Disable or remap my laptop's power button in Wayland [Hyprland]
Tapping the power button causes the system to power off, which isn't very convenient since it's right next to the delete button. I tried binding it in the hyprland.conf file to archlinux-logout but it still just powers down.
This solution has shed some light on the topic, but when I run xev and press the power key to find out if it's mapped to XF86PowerOff or whatever, the system turns off. So I'm not sure how to follow those instructions without knowing what the key is bound to at the system level.
Ideally I'd like to remap it to archlinux-logout. Running Arcolinux Hyprland on a 2013 Macbook Air.

I couldn't tell if this did anything, but I edited logind.conf:
sudo nano /etc/systemd/logind.conf
Add or uncomment the following lines:
HandlePowerKey=ignore
HandlePowerKeyLongPress=ignore
HandleLidSwitch=hibernate
PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=yes

Then in my hyprland.conf file, I added: bind = , xf86poweroff , exec, archlinux-logout
Now when I accidentally or intentionally tap on power key, my logout screen pops up.
